# Controle de produtos do carrinho

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express.js

Bom dia!

Estou fazendo um sistema onde o usuário escolhe os produtos (onde só tem 1 unidade de cada) e ele coloca esses produtos no carrinho. Preciso controlar esse carrinho por determinado tempo, quando esse tempo expirar preciso enviar uma mensagem para o usuário para saber se ele deseja continuar. Caso não deseje, preciso liberar o carrinho e liberar os bilhetes.

Como eu posso fazer o controle desse tempo, tipo usuário X entrou no site e escolheu produto 1, como bloquear esse produto 1 por 10 minutos? Caso entre usuário Y não consiga por no carrinho esse produto 1.

Comment: cria uma tabela e guarda essa informação, dai vai saber que tem N produtos a menos disponíveis

Comment: Mas o produto é único e só tem 1 unidade de cada produto. Eu preciso controlar o tempo que esse produto esta no carrinho pois, se não for realizado o pagamento do mesmo preciso liberar para outros usuários

Comment: exato, inclui o produto numa tabela, se ele existir lá é pq está no carrinho de alguem :)

Comment: mas é isso. Não posso deixar o produto pra sempre lá, por isso quero controlar o tempo que ele estar no carrinho de algum usuário

Comment: se já usou um carrinho de compras tipo ingressos sabe que ao por um item no carrinho, ele fica lá por XXX minutos depois expira, ou seja, tem que concluir o producesso de compra ou fica disponível. Nessa tabela de "controle" coloca a data/hora que adicionou o item, ou ainda quando for incluir põe a data que expira, por exemplo daqui a 20min. Quando consultar essa tabela olha essa data, se já expirou, remove o item da tabela e dispobiliza pra outro usuario

Comment: exatamente isso que eu preciso. Mas pelo que eu entendi, eu controlo cada produto. Tem como eu controlar um carrinho que possui vários produtos, os quais foram adicionados em tempo diferente? Por exemplo, o carrinho tenha um tempo de expiração (todos os produtos do carrinho)

Comment: ai vai da sua modelagem, pode ter 2 tabelas, 1 para o carrinho e outra para os itens do carrinho (produtos), ou usar um "id" carrinho na mesma tabela, já que é temporario